# Wordpress select image size as PHP Variable

Tags: php, image, wordpress, variables

Wordpress creates a new image URL for each of the sizes of images it creates when an image is uploaded. It adds the image size in pixels to the end of the string before the image extension. The problem is that if say an image size for a medium image is `300x300`, wordpress may crop it to say `300x180` to keep it in dimension.

This makes it difficult when programatically fetching a larger version of an image thumbnail as the file ending `-300x300.jpg` may not exist.

Is there a way of fetching the image by using the URL for the full image, with a PHP variable eg. `?size=medium` on the end that will load the correct version. I'm sure I have done this with older versions of wordpress but cannot find any documentation to prove this.

Comment: Try removing the trailing 300x300 from the name and then use the image name in your folder

Comment: Either you have to modify the function of upload image re-size or you have to upload the image as it is. If we don't know whether the admin will upload as it or not. Then we have to apply the reverse logic while we fetch the image and re-size proportionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

**$size**

Either a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large or full) or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g. array(32,32)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Add this to functions PHP so that the line above works for the first image if the post does not have a featured image.

```
function set_first_as_featured($attachment_ID){
    $post_ID = get_post($attachment_ID)->post_parent;
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)){
        set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachment_ID);
    }
}

add_action('add_attachment', 'set_first_as_featured');
add_action('edit_attachment', 'set_first_as_featured');
```

Comment: Thats fine for a featured image but not for another image. I've amended your code with a line in the functions PHP that should do the trick though when combined with this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a image size to use anywhere in your theme with **add_image_size**, see:

```
add_image_size( "your-custom-image-size", 300, 300, true );
```

then you can use in your theme as well:

```
the_post_thumbnail("your-custom-image-size", $attr);
```